# Can anyone find any Vulnerbility or Bugs In this function?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity

I have implemented this function and I think it has some Bugs and vulnerabilities this function so anyone can you help me to find the Vulnerability and bugs. I'm confused in this line

```
uint balance = address(this).balance;
```

and the next line to transfer the balance so is it possible for the hacker to use this line and transfer all the balance in his wallet?

```
function rescueNative() external{ 
        require(msg.sender == owner, "only owner");
        uint balance = address(this).balance;
        owner.transfer(balance);

        emit NativeRescued(address(this), balance);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If the value of `owner` is a smart contract address, one of two errors can happen:

1. If the `owner` contract doesn't implement the `fallback()` nor `receive()` special functions, the `transfer()` fails. Since your contract uses a deprecated Solidity version (it was not required to use `transfer()` on `address payable`, only on `address` in pre-0.8 versions), please also note that the fallback function in some older versions was a function without a name - simply `function () {}`
2. If the `owner` contract reenters the `rescueNative()` function from within its `fallback` or `receive` function, this might cause overflow if there's more than 1024 subsequent calls.

Other than that - assuming that this is a standalone function, not possible to call it from any other function, and that the `owner` is an EOA or a contract that is able to correctly receive funds, this snippet doesn't seem to show any more vulnerabilities.